# Initialising a pair of vectors and transforming them

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, std-pair

I would like to use a pair of vectors instead of *two vectors* in my transform functions, but don't know how I could possibly initialise the two vectors inside the `make_pair` function.

I have the following code and it works fine:

```
vector<Point> group_pts(size);
vector<int> group_rs(size);

std::transform(group.begin(), group.end(), group_pts.begin(), 
         [](const Circle& c1) -> Point { return c1.p;    } );
std::transform(group.begin(), group.end(), group_rs.begin(), 
         [](const Circle& c1) -> int { return c1.radius; } );
std::pair < vector<Point>, vector<int> > group_dscrp = make_pair(group_pts, group_rs);
return group_dscrp;
```

But, I need to have something like this but don't know how I should initialise

```
std::pair < vector<Point>, vector<int> > group_dscrp = INIT;

std::transform(group.begin(), group.end(), group_dscrp.first.begin(), 
              [](const Circle& c1) -> Point { return c1.p; } );

std::transform(group.begin(), group.end(), group_dscrp.second.begin(), 
              [](const Circle& c1) -> int {   return c1.radius; } );

return group_dscrp;
```

Comment: `std::pair < vector<Point>, vector<int> > group_dscrp{size, size}`? You can also use a `back_inserter` for the transform.

Comment: Why you have two vectors escapes me, rather than a single vector of `std::pair<Point,int>`, which could be transformed from your vector of `Circle` with a *single* transform. It at least appears there is a 1-1 correlation between `Point`s and radii.

Comment: all the above makes no sense to me! If I have a class which keeps point and radius, why someone need an additional vector of radius and point? Store the same information multiple times seems to be wrong. I can't see the use case! XY-Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is already mentioned in the comments(by @MatthieuBrucher).

```
std::pair<vector<Point>, vector<int>> group_dscrp{size, size}
```

will initialize the pair of vectors.

However, if you need a data structure which holds both `Point` and `radius` member of the `Circle`, you may wanna rethink with(as @WhozCraig mentioned)

```
std::vector<std::pair<Point, int>> group_dscrp
```

Now you can again either play with the `std::transform`

```
std::transform(group.cbegin(), group.cend(), std::back_inserter(group_dscrp), 
    [](const Circle& circle) {return std::pair<Point, int>{ circle.p, circle.radius };  });
```

or go for a simple range based loop to insert in to the `group_dscrp` as follows:

```
std::vector<Circle> group;
std::vector<std::pair<Point, int>> group_dscrp;
group_dscrp.reserve(size);
for (const Circle& circle : group) group_dscrp.emplace_back(circle.p, circle.radius);
```